# How to update a timestamp taken from server?

Tags: python

I have a very simple Python script in which I'm trying to print an updated timestamp (taken from a server by APIs) every `n` seconds.

After importing a custom module (FinexAPI) and the time module:

```
import FinexAPI
import time
```

and setting up the variable to get the server timestamp:

```
ticker = FinexAPI.ticker()
when = float(ticker['timestamp'])
```

if I perform:

```
print when
```

I'm getting the timestamp up to date. If I perform it again, I can see a new updated timestamp. Untill now there's no problem at all.

Now let's suppose I need to perform an "updated timestamp print" every 5 seconds:

```
def getNewTimestamp():
   print when
   time.sleep(5)

while True:
   getNewTimestamp()
```

But with this code I'm getting the same timestamp every 5 seconds. I suppose the problem is that I'm defining `when` outside the `getNewTimestamp` function, so it basically keeps printing the same non-updated timestamp. But even if I define it inside the function I still get no update on the timestamp.

Another thing I'm thinking about is that while loop is not the best choice in this scenario, but that would be another story (I think...). Can someone help me figuring out what am I doing wrong and what is the best way to obtain and print the updated timestamp every 5 seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the API in the loop:

```
def getNewTimestamp():
    ticker = FinexAPI.ticker()
    when = float(ticker['timestamp'])
    print when

while True:
    getNewTimestamp()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: you're the king!
that was so simple.
Thank you.
I gave you +1